# Create a TagHelper for JavaScript content

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

Did you saw the html tag  that makes the IDE know that the code inside is js?
When you create your custom taghelpers on mvc core it works for html content inside.
I wonder if there's a way of making my own tagHelper that receives js code like:

```
<customTagHelper>
//Some JS code here
</customTagHelper>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using an attribute selector for your tag helper instead so you can use a proper `<script>` tag.

Comment: For using js, is there any issue with using `@section Scripts`? Why did you want to implement your own script tag?

Comment: @Tao Poke Thank you for your answers. Im developing my mvc framework that has taghelpers for datatables. For example, with my framework you use <data-table-column asp-for="Name"> for rendering the name attribute of the collection. For rendering custom js function on fields i'd like the framework to allow you to add the js code inside the <data-table-column> tag instead of making an entirely separated function. It wold be cool if VS recognise the js code inside the tag for intelisense an so on.